# How to share karate html reports to others without sending as zip. If only html single file is sent then it shows as plain file

Tags: api, automation, cucumber, karate, bdd

I am using cucumber report with karate using the masterthought dependency. When the cucumber report is generated and if I want to share it to other I have to make a zip folder containing all the css, js etc folders along with the html file. If I only send the single html file alone it does not come up so well.
Anyone knows how to make it work with only single html file.

Comment: please assume that this is not directly supported and you should write your own report if needed

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas for quick response. I understand for cucumber report. Can you please confirm if this is the case with karate reports as well? Do you have any suggestion for sharing report which is generated by karate?

Comment: yes confirmed. I have nothing to add to the linked answer